# Newton-Raphson implementation, SymPy linsolve producing empty set?

Tags: python, algorithm, sympy

I wrote am implementation of the Newton-Raphson method (a multivariate generalization of Newton's method) to solve the system:

```
sqrt( (x - x_i) ** 2 + (y - y_i) ** 2 + (z - z_i) ** 2 ) - 299792458 * (t_i - t),
sqrt( (x - x_j) ** 2 + (y - y_j) ** 2 + (z - z_j) ** 2 ) - 299792458 * (t_j - t),
sqrt( (x - x_k) ** 2 + (y - y_k) ** 2 + (z - z_k) ** 2 ) - 299792458 * (t_k - t),
sqrt( (x - x_m) ** 2 + (y - y_m) ** 2 + (z - z_m) ** 2 ) - 299792458 * (t_m - t)
```

Where the unknowns are `x, y, z` and `t`. This system describes the solution to a localization problem, wherein the location of three observers, the velocity of some signal (in this case, `c = 299792458`), and the time at which the signal reached each observer is known, and we want to determine the coordinates `x, y, z` of the signal source (and, in doing so, we also find the time of emission, `t`).

I believe to understand the algorithm well. In this smaller example for solving the system:

```
10 * x + 3 * y * y - 3
x * x - exp(y) - 2
```

I attained excellent convergence, even with not-so-good initial guesses.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from sympy import *

x, y, z = symbols('x y z')


@dataclass
class Solve:

    @staticmethod
    def newton_raphson():

        F = Matrix([10 * x + 3 * y * y - 3, x * x - exp(y) - 2])
        v = Matrix([x, y])
        J = F.jacobian(v)

        xx, yy = 100000, 100000
        for i in range(100000):
            A = N(J.subs({"x": xx, "y": yy}))
            b = N(F.subs({"x": xx, "y": yy}))
            b *= -1

            update = linsolve((A, b), [x, y])

            (dx, dy) = tuple(*update)

            xx += dx
            yy += dy

            print(xx, yy)




mySolver = Solve
mySolver.newton_raphson()
```

**My Code:**

```
from sympy import *

x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
x_i, y_i, z_i, t_i = symbols('x_i y_i z_i t_i')
x_j, y_j, z_j, t_j = symbols('x_j y_j z_j t_j')
x_k, y_k, z_k, t_k = symbols('x_k y_k z_k t_k')
x_m, y_m, z_m, t_m = symbols('x_m y_m z_m t_m')


F = Matrix([
            sqrt( (x - x_i) ** 2 + (y - y_i) ** 2 + (z - z_i) ** 2 ) - 299792458 * (t_i - t),
            sqrt( (x - x_j) ** 2 + (y - y_j) ** 2 + (z - z_j) ** 2 ) - 299792458 * (t_j - t),
            sqrt( (x - x_k) ** 2 + (y - y_k) ** 2 + (z - z_k) ** 2 ) - 299792458 * (t_k - t),
            sqrt( (x - x_m) ** 2 + (y - y_m) ** 2 + (z - z_m) ** 2 ) - 299792458 * (t_m - t)
            ]).subs({'x_i': 1, 'y_i': 3, 'z_i': 5, 't_i': 3.678593478725817e-07,
                     'x_j': 2, 'y_j': 4, 'z_j': 6, 't_j': 3.6211297837266057e-07,
                     'x_k': 3, 'y_k': 6, 'z_k': 9, 't_k': 3.5014698296079636e-07,
                     'x_m': 5, 'y_m': 10, 'z_m': 15, 't_m': 3.26330717010967e-07})
J = F.jacobian([x, y, z, t])

#print(J, F)

def compute():
    xx, yy, zz, tt = 0, 0, 0, 0
    max_iter = 1000
    for i in range(max_iter):
        A = N(J.subs({'x': xx, 'y': yy, 'z': zz, 't': tt}))
        b = N(F.subs({'x': xx, 'y': yy, 'z': zz, 't': tt})) * -1

        update = linsolve((A, b), [x, y, z, t])

        print(update)

        (dx, dy, dz, dt) = tuple(*update)

        xx += dx
        yy += dy
        zz += dz
        tt += dt

    print('(x, y, z):', xx, yy, zz)

compute()
```

I "simulated" a source with some random coordinates, and chose the coordinates of the observers to be:

```
x_i = 1
y_i = 3
z_i = 5

x_j = 2
y_j = 4
z_j = 6

x_k = 3
y_k = 6
z_k = 9

x_m = 5
y_m = 10
z_m = 15
```

To produce times of arrival of:

`3.678593478725817e-07 3.6211297837266057e-07 3.5014698296079636e-07 3.26330717010967e-07`

**My Problem:**

The code above is throwing the error:

```
    (dx, dy, dz, dt) = tuple(*update)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 0)
```

It seems that `linsolve` is producing an `EmptySet`, though I'm not sure why? Note that this shouldn't be an issue with the solvability of this system. It is my understanding that Newton-Raphson is the "standard" technique used in solving this problem.

**Edit:**

It seems that `A` is:

```
Matrix([[-0.169030850945703, -0.507092552837110, -0.845154254728517, 299792458.000000], 
        [-0.267261241912424, -0.534522483824849, -0.801783725737273, 299792458.000000], 
        [-0.267261241912424, -0.534522483824849, -0.801783725737273, 299792458.000000], 
        [-0.267261241912424, -0.534522483824849, -0.801783725737273, 299792458.000000]])
```

And `b` is:

```
Matrix([[104.365378313899], 
        [101.075425086493], 
        [93.7464525227794], 
        [79.1232008397505]])
```

So `A` is singular... not sure what I've done wrong?

**Update:**

I've made *some* progress. I fed the algorithm these times:

`4.456421305318992e-07 4.398748057660546e-07 4.2865257523627983e-07 4.064283790801526e-07`

Which correspond to the coordinates:

`83 81 76`

i.e., that's what I expect my NR code to produce. By changing my initial values to `100, 100, 100` (which are fairly good starting points, I think), I was able to avoid the singular matrix issue most of the time. Now, however, I'm getting nowhere near the sort of values I'm expecting. Again, I want `83 81 76`, but I'm getting (where each line is a step in Newton's method):

```
(x, y, z): 17456269941258.7 -34912544447499.9 17456272342079.8
(x, y, z): 227660996986076. -376466056005027. 222965719150785.
(x, y, z): -1.21023496190953e+15 2.13688425095421e+15 -726879053110979.
(x, y, z): 4.90735107057989e+17 -1.41978303824902e+17 -1.26827668619485e+17
(x, y, z): -321561212.117731*t + 0.289317600845958*y - 4.1103972009836e+17 y - 1.41978303824902e+17 -1.26827668619485e+17
(x, y, z): -321561212.117731*t + 0.289317600845958*y - 4.1103972009836e+17 + 1.0*(8.01168826792966e-19*t**2*y*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 - 8.01168826792966e-19*t**2*y*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 - 0.113748591105452*t**2*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 + 0.113748591105452*t**2*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 - 7.20833962883084e-28*t*y**2*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 + 7.20833962883084e-28*t*y**2*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 + 1.64883758053215e-9*t*y*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 + 6.55493667660098e-10*t*y*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**1.0 - 1.64883758053215e-9*t*y*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 - 6.55493667660098e-10*t*y*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**1.0 + 1.33659310664116e-26*t*z - 219568708.172346*t*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 - 93065879.1023445*t*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**1.0 + 219568708.172346*t*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 + 93065879.1023445*t*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**1.0 - 3.77928683421434e-19*y**2*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 - 5.89765954818281e-19*y**2*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**1.0 + 3.77928683421434e-19*y**2*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 + 5.89765954818281e-19*y**2*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**1.0 + 0.644246732305085*y*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 + 1.00536107970607*y*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**1.0 - 0.644246732305085*y*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 - 1.00536107970607*y*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**1.0 + 1.4351559202707e-17*z - 8.38508328353584e+16*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 - 1.30851053806647e+17*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**1.0 + 8.38508328353584e+16*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 + 1.30851053806647e+17*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**1.0)/(-3.38882283462319e-35*t**2 + 3.04901852355942e-44*t*y - 8.40342129428199e-26*t + 3.27385871089648e-35*y - 5.11605818702297e-17) y - 1.41978303824902e+17 + (-0.393024115662512*t**2*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 + 0.393024115662512*t**2*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 + 3.53614770479379e-10*t*y*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 - 3.53614770479379e-10*t*y*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 - 758653768.964884*t*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 - 321561212.117731*t*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**1.0 + 758653768.964884*t*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 + 321561212.117731*t*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**1.0 + 0.185397985565395*y*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 + 0.289317600845958*y*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**1.0 - 0.185397985565395*y*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 - 0.289317600845958*y*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**1.0 - 2.89721385578571e+17*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 - 4.52116542333159e+17*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**1.0 + 2.89721385578571e+17*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**0.5 + 4.52116542333159e+17*(4.29671948342487e-19*t**2 - 7.73175697569789e-28*t*y + 1.2082414688189e-9*t + 4.50319375723489e-36*y**2 - 2.26703331823469e-18*y + 1)**1.0)/(5.16987882845642e-26*t + 5.55111512312578e-17) z - 1.26827668619485e+17
```

Which is... not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If x, y and z are all equal then the matrix is singular:

```
In [26]: F                                                                                                                        
Out[26]: 
⎡                  ________________________________                    ⎤
⎢                 ╱        2          2          2                     ⎥
⎢ 299792458⋅t + ╲╱  (x - 1)  + (y - 3)  + (z - 5)   - 110.281458096998 ⎥
⎢                                                                      ⎥
⎢                  ________________________________                    ⎥
⎢                 ╱        2          2          2                     ⎥
⎢ 299792458⋅t + ╲╱  (x - 2)  + (y - 4)  + (z - 6)   - 108.558739860041 ⎥
⎢                                                                      ⎥
⎢                  ________________________________                    ⎥
⎢                 ╱        2          2          2                     ⎥
⎢ 299792458⋅t + ╲╱  (x - 3)  + (y - 6)  + (z - 9)   - 104.971424683101 ⎥
⎢                                                                      ⎥
⎢                 __________________________________                   ⎥
⎢                ╱        2           2           2                    ⎥
⎣299792458⋅t + ╲╱  (x - 5)  + (y - 10)  + (z - 15)   - 97.8314877736202⎦

In [27]: F.jacobian([x, y, z, t]).subs({y:x, z:x}).det()                                                                          
Out[27]: 0
```

It is possible to solve this system exactly but a bit of work is needed. We rearrange for the square roots and square everything and then solve (this technique can induce spurious solutions):

```
In [50]: getsqrt = lambda e: list((a for a in e.atoms(Pow) if a.exp == S.Half))[0]                                                

In [51]: eqs = [getsqrt(e)**2-solve(e, getsqrt(e))[0]**2 for e in F]                                                              

In [52]: solve(eqs, [x, y, z, t])                                                                                                 
Out[52]: 
[(55.9999999982927, 67.0000000004083, 75.9999999981356, 6.05322891533058e-18), (56.6666666664221, 65.6666666641494, 76.666666666
265, 6.05322891533058e-18)]
```

We can find one of these using `nsolve`:

```
In [56]: nsolve(F, [x, y, z, t], [100, 99, 100, 1])                                                                               
Out[56]: 
⎡  56.6666666669817   ⎤
⎢                     ⎥
⎢   65.666666666105   ⎥
⎢                     ⎥
⎢  76.6666666669866   ⎥
⎢                     ⎥
⎣-1.41498771053963e-19⎦
```

The result for t is different but they are both basically saying that `t=0`.

In general the reason that this is tricky is that the matrix is badly scaled e.g.:

```
In [78]: F.jacobian([x, y, z, t]).subs({x:51, y:55, z:60, t:1}).n().eigenvals()                                                   
Out[78]: {-0.0120397251584435: 1, -8.56399289233542e-5: 1, 0.00115898129572641: 1, 299792459.731957: 1}
```